# point cloud library PCL Ptr pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>)

Tags: point-cloud-library

```cpp
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>)
```

What is this variable `Ptr` here ? I tried to find it out but could not get any relevant information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) maybe you will get more answers...

Answer (score 3):

Relevant information is online if you go looking for it.

The PCL [documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html) will tell you what `Ptr` is.

> ```
> typedef boost::shared_ptr< PointCloud<PointT> >   Ptr
> ```

i.e. `Ptr` is a typedef to a smart pointer of the Boost library.

Then, any C++ documentation will tell you what a [typedef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) is, and Boost documentation will tell you what a [smart pointer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) is.

(`cloud` is the variable here, not `Ptr`. `Ptr` is part of the type.)

The [PCL basic tutorials](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#basic-usage) is what you need to go through.